# What flower is this?

Tags: botany, species-identification, flowers

I received this flower as a gift.

[image: The flower]

So far, I couldn't identify what flower it is. My family thinks it may be either some sort of *Clematis* or an [*Ipomoea purpurea*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ipomoea_purpurea).
The main reason I want to identify this flower is to know if it can live outside most of the year (I live in France).

Comment: my first impression was that it was mandevilla. We had this plant in a pot on the porch when I was growing up. The plant stayed outside until winter (temps typically below 0 C for 3 months) at which point we stored it inside. Mostly dies back each winter and we clipped it. Each summer, we put it back outside and it grew nice and big again.

Answer (score 2):

The leaves are most similar to [this Mandevilla](https://www.google.fr/search?q=%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BF%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F+%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%89%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5&num=100&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi0q5Or3K3TAhXEfhoKHctVBicQ_AUICCgB&biw=894&bih=567)

It may be a hybrid [periwinkle](https://www.google.fr/search?q=periwinkle&num=100&espv=2&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjGzarZ2q3TAhXG1hoKHaCCCj4Q_AUICCgB&biw=894&bih=567), in France and UK there are blue ones in wild and there are pink ones i.e. in Madagascar. If it's a periwinkle you can tell by the fruit and veins of the leaves. It can be a variant of [*Vinca minor*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vinca_minor). It has evergreen type leaves, it may be tropical. It is also similar to the Oleander family. *Clematis* and *Ipomea* have new foliage every year.

Also see [this](https://www.google.fr/search?q=giant+sun+parasol+flower+pink&num=100&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiFgZHM3K3TAhVMWhoKHYrmDeIQ_AUICCgB&biw=894&bih=567).

Answer (score 1):

@comprehensible is right: it's a *Mandevilla*, most likely the *Mandevilla sanderi* which is common in cultivation.

You can find further information on [wikipedia](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mandevilla), and of course on a lot of gardening sites.